# How to sample from a normal distribution random values inside a range using Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I have two variables `mean` and `stddev` which are tensors of shape (1,) and they represent many normal distributions with mean lets say mean[i] and stardard deviation stddev[i].

From these distributions I want to sample one value within a range in [`low`,`up`,] for everyones and then I want to get the log probabilities of the sampled values.

From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Normal#experimental_sample_and_log_prob) I found that the `experimental_sample_and_log_prob` method is almost for me because it does not sample elements within a range of values (low, up) that I would like to have.

So I coded few lines but it doesn't work very well naturally ad it is so computationally expensive.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd


def sample_and_log_prob(dist, up, down):
    samples = dist.sample()
    accepted = False
    print("Is {} accepted? {}".format(samples, accepted))
    while not accepted:
        # sample < up
        cond1 = tf.less_equal(samples, up)
        # sample > down
        cond2 = tf.greater_equal(samples, down)
        # if down < sample < up
        accepted = tf.logical_and(cond1, cond2) 
        samples = tf.where(
            tf.logical_not(accepted),
            samples,
            dist.sample())
        print("Is {} accepted? {}".format(samples, accepted))
    
    return samples, dist.log_prob(samples)


distribution = tfd.Normal(
    loc=mean ,
    scale=stddev,
    validate_args=True,
    allow_nan_stats=False)

samples, log_probs = sample_and_log_prob(distribution, up=-1, down=1)
```

Any tips to solve it?

Comment: "it doesn't work very well" is not programming statement. What does this mean? What is the specific issue you are having?

Comment: I mean it is very expensive in terms of computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `TruncatedNormal` distribution.